# FLOW3 authentication Login form error

Tags: php, typo3-flow

I tried to create a login form in the Flow3 PHP framework, but I got this error:

```
Might be missing or wrong credentials or no authentication provider matched.
```

Does anyone know how to create login form in detail than link below?

http://www.layh.com/work/flow3-fluid/tutorials/flow3-registration-and-login.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a recent version of FLOW3? I believe that in the 1.1 releases the defaultAuthenticationProvider setting was deprecated.